# export coordinate from an image to excel format in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, coordinates

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgmMi.png) image that has been converted to binary, all I need is the coordinate data (x-y) of all the white pixels but in excel format (.xlsx or .xls) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D3YW.png), how do I get it?

Previously, I've tried in Matlab using `bw.boundaries` command, but all I got was the coordinates of the edges (not the full area). Now i want to do it in python, is there a way to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, don't save bi-level images as JPEG. Your JPEG has 240 shades of grey because JPEG is lossy! Second, please be more precise as to what you want - do you want a CSV? How will the first few lines look? Please give an example. Then what do you mean by *"you want the coordinate data of the white areas"* - do you mean you want the x,y coordinates of every single white pixel?

Comment: You don't need to write any Python by the way. You can do it with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal with `magick IMAGE.JPG -threshold 50% txt: | awk -F: '/white/{print $1}' > data.csv`

Comment: i am so sorry for the lack of information, i've edited the question and changed the image.

Comment: oh i've never used ImageMagick before but i'll try, thank you! i'll inform you after i try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import imageio
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

im = rgb2gray(imageio.imread("img.jpg"))

np.savetxt('img.csv', np.argwhere(img > 0.5), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

or if your image is stored as `uint8`

```
np.savetxt('img.csv', np.argwhere(img > 127), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

or if your image is stored as a binary array

```
np.savetxt('img.csv', np.argwhere(img != 0), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

**EDIT:** *a little example for OP to hopefully better understand how this works*

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

# let's load a sample image
cat = imageio.imread('imageio:chelsea.png')   

# let's turn it into b/w by thresholding the read channel
cat_bw = cat[..., 0] > 127

# now we can get the white pixel coordinates
white_coords = np.argwhere(cat_bw)

# you could save them to csv with
np.savetxt('img.csv', white_coords, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

you would get something like

```
$ cat img.csv
0,0
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
[...]
299,445
299,446
299,447
299,448
299,449
299,450
```

Not sure how are you going to process them in Excel, that is beyond my expertise but let's say you want make be sure the coordinates are what we want them to be.

Let's plot our b/w chelsea (`cat_bw`):

[image: bwchelsea]

Now let's try to turn our coordinates in the original image to another color, let's make it pink in a super-dumb not numpythonic way:

```
for x, y in white_coords: 
    cat[x, y] = [219, 49, 190]
```

and plot it:

[image: pink chelsea]

So, it seems to me the `white_coords` array, and the csv file where we saved them, do actually contain our white pixel coordinates.

Comment: i've tried your code but it didnt work, the coordinate form a box not like the image :(

Comment: @GrisheldaAthallah what did you try? how can you say it's a box? please share more information about your tests and how can I reproduce them

Comment: I've used the code that you sent. After getting the coordinate data in csv format, I convert it to xlsx and make a diagram in excel. But the plot results form a box (it looks like the code only reads the outer white box, not the white pixel area inside the box)

Comment: the result I want is coordinates of each white pixels in the image so that I can plot it using Excel and produce the same shape. Sorry if I confused you at the beginning

Comment: @GrisheldaAthallah please see my edit, you didn't confuse me I think, it's just I'm missing some element to understand where it's not working, but it works, as my edit suggests